# Tomcat + Mysql - Unable to find java:comp

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, servlets, tomcat7

i'm trying to use tomcat + mysql to develop Web Application and this is my configuration:

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="EntityMappings" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>
        java:comp/env/jdbc/EntityMappings
    </non-jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                  value="none" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

web.xml

```
    <resource-ref>
    <description>MySQL Datasource example</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/EntityMappings</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

context.xml(under tomcat/config)

```
<Resource name="jdbc/EntityMappings" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="XXX" password="XXX" 
           driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EntityMappings"/>
```

My schema is EntityMappings.

After running it i got some errors:

```
Name [java:comp/env/jdbc/EntityMappings] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:comp].

Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/EntityMappings]

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
```

i have placed the mysql driver under my tomcat/lib (mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar)

Comment: Please post you Spring configuration as well

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the java:comp/env prefix from your persistence.xml:

```
<non-jta-data-source>
    jdbc/EntityMappings
</non-jta-data-source>
```